# Angular change detection with pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular2-changedetection

I have an issue with change detection and pipe. I could not find a good way to work around it.

I have created a small project to reproduce it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7eqbg6). Go to the /monitor route.

When you click on the on Change button, it changes the value of the first item in the array but the UI is not updated.

It works if I recreate another object in the change handler with

```
this.state[0] = Object.assign({}, this.state[0], { value: 999.99 });
```

But I don't want to do that. I need to keep the same object reference.

The issue comes from the pipe in vital-value.component.html

```
{{ _vitalValue | vitalFormat }}
```

It works if I use instead

```
{{ _vitalValue.value }}
```

Is there a way to keep the pipe but to make the refresh happen?

Thanks!

Comment: > 404: page missing is getting displayed on StackBlitz.

Comment: Try using `this.state = [...this.state];` after you change the value.

Comment: @Siddharth Ajmera Yes, go to the /monitor route. Updated the post...

Comment: Changing it to impure works. Did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is not recommended, try making the pipe impure.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'vitalFormat',
  pure: false
})
```

But beware of the consequences to your App's performance. It's not really recommended to use `impure` pipes.

Read through here:

> Angular executes an impure pipe during every component change detection cycle. An impure pipe is called often, as often as every keystroke or mouse-move.
>
> With that concern in mind, implement an impure pipe with great care. An expensive, long-running pipe could destroy the user experience.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for the hint to pure/impure pipes. It is working with this change. I read through this article (https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-pure-and-impure-pipes-and-why-that-matters-999818aa068) and have a better understanding of the issue.